# Parse Live Queries on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-live-query

Are live queries for the Parse SDK not available for iOS? There is a guide for it under the android menu on back4app but nothing for iOS. All of the information currently on guides only refers to JavaScript and nothing seems to be listed for obj-c or swift either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveQuery works great on iOS and actually works better than the other SDKS. Some docs below: https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift#livequery

https://swiftpackageindex.com/netreconlab/parse-swift/5.4.1/documentation/parseswift/parselivequery

Feature comparison: https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/discussions/72

Coding examples:

https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/blob/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/11%20-%20LiveQuery.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

https://github.com/netreconlab/Parse-Swift/blob/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/19%20-%20SwiftUI%20-%20LiveQuery.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Comment: Pretty neat. Is it possible to do in Obj-C, or is it just Swift? I'm not wanting something as complex as a chat app or anything. Just looking to incorporate a feature similar to a live activity. When viewing a presentation made on an Apple TV app, advancing it would trigger the server, and then correspond with the slide number on iOS app, letting user know on phone where they were in the presentation, and all the existing code is still in Obj-C

Comment: ParseSwift is only for Swift, if you want Objective-C you will need to use https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX and https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX. You can see the difference in features from the link in my original post

Comment: I followed instructions for Pod install, and it gave me error messages '/ParseLiveQuery/Client.swift:11:8 Could not build Objective-C module 'Parse'

Comment: I don't manage the Objective-C Parse frameworks (I do manage the ParseSwift one I linked), I recommend you comment/open issues on the respective repos you are running with.